# Blender3d vs 3DS max; which one is better suited for automation in python?

Tags: python, blender, panda3d

I am getting started with the development of 3d environments for using in panda3d. As I am new to this, I need to choose a modelling software to create basic geometries, etc. Therefore, which one is better suited for automation through python? 3DS Max or Blender3D? I would like to automate generating basic geometries, the export process and some basic animations. Blender has the benefit of being free, but my office will provide me the licenses for 3DS if I request, so that is not a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a python automation point of view, blender itself is written largely in python, and the source is available which allows a level of automation not possible if you can't change the source.  To me, having the source available in that situation is more of a benefit than the price tag.

If you do go with blender, definitely grab the 2.5 beta.  They made some *huge* UI and scripting improvements.  In my opinion, most of the complaints about it being difficult to learn compared to commercial packages are no longer valid for 2.5, especially if you don't have the mental burden of already having learned another software's interface.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know blender is written in python; this is very cool. I am installing 2.5 beta right now.

Comment: Well, the deeper you get into blender, the more of it is written in C, but at the higher levels where you're more likely to experiment/personalize it's python.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the poster Karl Bielefldt is wrong. Blender is not written in python is written in C. What is written in python is some script tools, python is used as blender's script engine , but in the end what is triggered are C libraries. That is not big deal though since python itself is written in C.

However all this is totally unrelated to your question.

Since the engine you are going to use is third party and not the game engine of blender, there is no reason for you to consider Blender as a mandatory choice. Any 3d package can serve you well. This is because as other kind of software, 3d software has several formats that are common ammong 3d apps. Like *.3ds and *.obj . So that means that you can use anything you wish like Maya, XSi, Ciname 4d , anything. As almost 3d software saves to these common file formats.

However I would strongly advice to take a look at blender game engine. The blender game engine automates alot of things and has a gui inside blender that minimises coding unlike Panda 3d which requires everything to be coded regarding the engine.

You can save loads of time with blender's game engine.

There is even a blender game that was developed using solely with the blender game engine , its called project apricot or Yo Fankie.

[Apricot Project](http://www.yofrankie.org/)

You can download it for free and see the source to help you learn loads of things for Blender Game engine.

Good luck.